# How to Make Checkboxes Into Array In Dreamweaver

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, dreamweaver

I am designing a seat reservation system. I want the check boxes to represent the seats.
I want to know how to make each check boxes into array and how to group all the check boxes in a single canvas so that it will store multiple values in one single variable in the database column.

I am using Dreamweaver and PHP.

Comment: Please add some code with what you have started with & exactly where stuck with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should do some like below:

```
<input type="checkbok" value="1" name="seat[]" />
<input type="checkbok" value="2" name="seat[]" />
<input type="checkbok" value="3" name="seat[]" />
<input type="checkbok" value="4" name="seat[]" />
....
```